# AttributeError: _get_numeric_data ; Iris Dataset

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I picked up a book and am trying to teach myself machine learning. I'm at the point where we are visualizing the data to see if it is good to use in machine learning.

My code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import mglearn
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
iri = load_iris()

xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = train_test_split(iri['data'], iri['target'], random_state=0)

print(xTrain.shape)

iriFrame = pd.DataFrame(xTrain, columns=iri.feature_names)
pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(iri, c=yTrain, figsize=(15, 15), marker='o', hist_kwds={'bins':20}, s=60, alpha=.8, cmap=mglearn.cm3)
#print('Keys: \n{}'.format(iri.keys()))
#print(iri['data'])
#print(iri['feature_names'])
```

The error I receive states that:

```
runfile('/home/jack/Desktop/PythonProjects/code/flowers.py', wdir='/home/jack/Desktop/PythonProjects/code')
(112, 4)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-19-b6a377fa4d9d>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/jack/Desktop/PythonProjects/code/flowers.py', wdir='/home/jack/Desktop/PythonProjects/code')

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/jack/Desktop/PythonProjects/code/flowers.py", line 13, in <module>
    pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(iri, c=yTrain, figsize=(15, 15), marker='o', hist_kwds={'bins':20}, s=60, alpha=.8, cmap=mglearn.cm3)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_misc.py", line 56, in scatter_matrix
    df = frame._get_numeric_data()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 104, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(key)

AttributeError: _get_numeric_data
```

This seems like an error that might have to do with the set up of my install packages, but I'm not sure. Could anyone give some advice on whats happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pd.plotting.scatter_matrix()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix.html) is expecting a DataFrame as first argument, use `iriFrame`  instead of `iri`

```
pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(iriFrame, c=yTrain, figsize=(15, 15), marker='o', hist_kwds={'bins':20}, s=60, alpha=.8, cmap=mglearn.cm3)
```

[image]